# Add custom validation to JWT token for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

Previously, I was able to use `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` to add my custom token handler with my custom validation.  Now with Core `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` I need to use `JwtBearerOptions` which doesn't seem to have an option to override `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.  I basically want to override the following method in `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`:

```
protected virtual JwtSecurityToken ValidateSignature(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
```

Previously:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenHandler = new MyTokenHandler()
    // other properties here
});
```

Currently with ASP.NET Core:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    // other properties here
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to actually create your own `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and override the `ValidateSignature` method, you can use the `SecurityTokenValidators` property:

```
var options new JwtBearerOptions();
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenHandler());
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
```

Technically the call to `Clear()` isn't necessary - as long as one of the token handlers can parse the token the call to authenticate will succeed. However removing the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` seems to make sense if it won't ever succeed in your case.

Comment: This line `options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();` save my times. Thanks a lot

Comment: How I can return error from Customer token handler - ValidateToken Method?

Answer (score 0):

`JwtBearerOptions` has a parameter named `TokenValidationParameters`, so you can use this parameter:

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
    //...
};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    //...
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});
```

Comment: Yea I looked at TokenValidationParameters but couldn't figure out how to do my own token validation. In particular I want to validate the signature and I can't figure out how to do that with TokenValidationParameters.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If no what is your token validation logic, could you post it?

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  There just isn't a TokenHandler property in JwtBearerOptions like there was in JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions.